# What BLDC servo drive takes sinusoidal hall sensor signals?

Tags: brushless-motor, hall-sensor

I am looking for a servo drive to control a brushless DC motor, with at least 10A, 30V rating. However, I want to know if any exist which take sinusoidal hall sensor signals directly.

I already know there are servo drives taking hall sensor pulses (with 6 different phases), but that is trapezoidal control.

Note: a servo drive includes the driving electronics (no additional transistors required).

Comment: I worked on a Cartesian robot with a similar spec amplifiers for it's linear motors and they had sinusoidal halls, but I'm afraid I can't remember what make they were. Sorry I can't be more helpful, but knowing they are probably out there might be encouraging at least.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes they are called linear halls.

A company called Eltrol used to make drives for these. I used them in the past in combination with Anorad Linear motors. Nowadays they are still available from PeakServo.
The drives drive the linear (or sine) hall and receive the two halll signal (which are 120 degrees apart).

http://www.peakservo.com/series-45-linear-hall-sine-servo-amplifier/